# DOS Assembler: MOV ah, 09h AND int 21h combination doesn't print anything

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, tasm

I'm writing a DOS commandline arguments parser on TASM assembly language. Here's my code:

```
.model tiny
.386
.code
org 100h
start:


    mov ax, ax  
    mov bp, 80h
    mov si, 81h
    mov ch, 0
    mov cl, ds:[bp]
    push 0
    cmp cx, 0
    je FINISH

    CYCLE_BEGIN:
        lodsb
        cmp al, 2Fh
        je SLASH
        cmp al, 31h
        je ONE
        cmp al, 32h
        je TWO
        cmp al, 33h
        je THREE
        cmp al, 68h
        je HELP
        cmp al, 20h
        je SPACE
        mov bx, 6
        jmp CHANGE_STATE

        SLASH:
            mov bx, 0
            jmp CHANGE_STATE
        ONE:
            mov bx, 1
            jmp CHANGE_STATE
        TWO:
            mov bx, 2
            jmp CHANGE_STATE
        THREE:
            mov bx, 3
            jmp CHANGE_STATE
        HELP:
            mov bx, 4
            jmp CHANGE_STATE
        SPACE:
            mov bx, 5
        CHANGE_STATE:
            mov ax, 7
            mul dx
            add ax, bx
            mov dh, 0
            push si
            mov si, offset AU
            add si, ax
            lodsb
            mov dl, al
            pop si

        cmp dx, 6
        JE ERROR

        cmp dx, 1
        je HAVEONE
        cmp dx, 2
        je HAVETWO
        cmp dx, 3
        je HAVETHREE
        cmp dx, 4
        je HAVEHELP
        jmp CYCLE_END

        HAVEONE:
            mov ax, 0001h
            jmp SETFLAGS
        HAVETWO:
            mov ax, 0010h
            jmp SETFLAGS
        HAVETHREE:
            mov ax, 0100h
            jmp SETFLAGS
        HAVEHELP:
            mov ax, 1000h
        SETFLAGS:
            pop bx
            or bx, ax
            push bx
        CYCLE_END:
            dec cx
            jne CYCLE_BEGIN
    jmp SUCCESS
    ERROR:
        pop bx
        mov dx, offset merror
        mov ah, 09h
        int 21h
        jmp FINISH
    SUCCESS:
    pop bx
    mov dx, bx
    and dx, 1000h
    je MESSAGES_CHECK
    mov dx, offset mhelp
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
    jmp FINISH

    MESSAGES_CHECK:
    mov dx, bx
    and dx, 0001h
    je CHECK2
    mov dx, offset m1
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
    mov ah, 02h
    mov dl, 0dh
    int 21h
    mov dl, 0ah
    int 21h

    CHECK2:
    mov dx, bx
    and dx, 0010h
    je CHECK3
    mov dx, offset m2
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
    mov ah, 02h
    mov dl, 0dh
    int 21h
    mov dl, 0ah
    int 21h
    CHECK3:
    mov dx, bx
    and dx, 0100h
    je FINISH
    mov dx, offset m3
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    FINISH:
        RET

        m1  db  'You have used /1 key$'
        m2  db  'You have used /2 key$'
        m3  db  'You have used /3 key$'
        mhelp   db  'ad.asm [/1 | /2 | /3| /h]$'
        merror  db  'Wrong input$'

        AU:;        / 1 2 3 h   *
        db  5,6,6,6,6,0,6 ;
        db  6,6,6,6,6,0,6 ; /1
        db  6,6,6,6,6,0,6 ; /2
        db  6,6,6,6,6,0,6 ; /3
        db  6,6,6,6,6,0,6 ; /h
        db  6,1,2,3,4,6,6 ; /
        db  6,6,6,6,6,6,6 ; err



end start
```

It should print `m1`'s content if there is `/1`, `m2`'s if `/2`and `m3`'s if `/3`. The problem is in this code parts:

```
mov dx, offset m1
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
----

mov dx, offset m2
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
----

mov dx, offset m3
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
```

It doesn't print anything. Even if I see in Turbo Debugger that the code is reached and there is right offset in `dx`, there is no text in stdout after `int 21h`. Why?

Comment: I could only check using dosbox, and it works fine there.

Comment: @Jester How did you compile the code?

Comment: `tasm test.asm` and `tlink /t test.obj`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multiplication at CHANGE_STATE makes no sense since DX was not initialized beforehand!

```
CHANGE_STATE:
        mov ax, 7
        mul dx
```

Hope this helps.

Also because you're using string primitives `lodsb`you could make sure to clear the direction flag `cld`.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Problem is reproducible on a real Win95 machine (all messages except 'Wrong input' are swallowed); problem disappears when adding `xor dx,dx` at the start of the source code. By the way, the problem did **not** occur in Turbo Debug (e.g. `td test.com /1`), as all registers (including `dx`) are initialized with zero there. Maybe OP _thought_ the problem still occurred because all output is cleared when exiting TD. If you press Alt-F5 to inspect console output while debugging, then you will see the messages alright.

Answer (score -2):

A DOS .com application stores all its code and data in only one segment and DS and ES are already initialized and equal to CS when it starts to execute.

...

For to get some commandline arguments, it is recommended for to get the segment address of the PSP before, because the current PSP is not necessarily the caller's PSP, if we start a child application from within a parent application with the exec function AX=4B00h of the int 21h for example.

RBIL->inter61b.zip->INTERRUP.H

```
--------D-2162-------------------------------
INT 21 - DOS 3.0+ - GET CURRENT PSP ADDRESS
AH = 62h
Return: BX = segment of PSP for current process
Notes:  this function does not use any of the DOS-internal stacks and may
thus be called at any time, even during another INT 21h call
the current PSP is not necessarily the caller's PSP
identical to the undocumented AH=51h
SeeAlso: AH=50h,AH=51h
```

Comment: This answer doesn't make any sense. You need to use the program's own PSP to access the program's own command line arguments. In a .COM executable DS, ES, CS are all initialized to point to the PSP segment. That's the reason for the `ORG 100h` statement, to skip over the PSP that's located at the beginning of the segment.